# how to do Cross-Origin-Request from Firebase Hosting to AWS Lambda function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, firebase-hosting

pardon me I'm new to webdev.

I have a simple single page webpage hosted on firebase hosting that gets some information from an aws lambda function (i didn't use google cloud cause it didn't let me do outbound requests for free).

The lambda function doesn't take any input. Think of it as a random number generator.

This is how the client requests:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "thatAWSLambdaURL",
          crossDomain: true,
          xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
          },
          method: 'GET',
          success: function(data){
            console.log('succes: '+data);
          }
        });
```

but instead I get this error in log:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://someAWSLambdaUrl.amazonaws.com/default/someurl. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).[Learn More]
```

​

I have even configured my lambda function's API Gateway to `Enabled CORs` with `Access-Control-Allow-Header` set as `'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set as `"*"`.

If I request the lambda function locally from Firefox or a simple python script it works flawlessly. This only happens when I request from webpage. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the lambda docs on cors found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

it looks like you need to return the appropriate headers within your lambda function.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, I have already configured my lambda function. Infact, I had followed that exact same doc.

Comment: You enabled cors on api gateway, not on the lambda function

Comment: Interesting. Lemme try I'll reply in 5mins.

Comment: okay so I went and added `headers: {
            "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "my-origin.com"
        },` to my response but it still doesn't work.

I'm a noob so can you tell exactly what to set the headers to?